# 3d plot for function defined for integer values

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a plot of a function defined just for integer values, like

```
f[n_, m_] := 2 - (1/IntegerPart[n]) - (1/IntegerPart[m])
```

If I try to plot

```
Plot3D[f[n, m], {n, 1, 6}, {m, 1, 6}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> None, 
ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"]
```

I need this 100 points to get a "decent" result. This takes a long time, and the 
result is not very similar as the histogram one. Do you know if there is anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's `ListPointPlot3D` and `ListPlot3D`.  But I'm confused: If `1 <= n <=6` and `1 <= m <= 6` and `n`, `m` are integers, then there are only 36 points.

Comment: Sorry, I didn copied propperly, now is updated.
THe problem in doing the `ListPlot3D` does only plot a point, I would like to have the chart bars aspect, like in the `Histogram3D` case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
DiscretePlot3D[f[n, m], {n, 1, 6}, {m, 1, 6}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", ExtentSize -> Full]
```

[image: Plot of function]

Comment: Awesome!
You saved my life! I million thanks ;)